# Recursive function to keep updating a data frame in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am having trouble getting my head wrapped around this.
So I have a dataframe with this setup
**Original dataframe**

| OntoDataRid | ObjRidB | Name | Object | Child_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BlahBlah | BlobBlob | Somthing | rd.111 | rd.123 |
| BlahBlah2 | BlobBlob2 | Somthing2 | rd.123 | rd.567 |

**Desired DataFrame**

| OntoDataRid | ObjRidB | Name | Object | Child_1 | Child_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BlahBlah | BlobBlob | Somthing | rd.111 | rd.123 | rd.567 |
| BlahBlah2 | BlobBlob2 | Somthing2 | rd.123 | rd.567 | Null |

And what I need to do is look at the object and the `child_1` columns and to recursively find the child in the object and make that a `Child_2`
So an object has a child which is listed in `Child_1`
However, `Child_1` could also have a child, but this relationship is shown in the same way. This means that the `child_1` is also listed as an object field with a child in `child_1`.

So what I need to do is to recursively look at `child_1` find the string in the `Object` column then make a new column `Child_X` and place the child of `Child_1` (Currently the `Object`) into `Child_X` column and then do the same for `child_x` until `child_x` is all nulls. This would mean there are no other children.

I gave this a few tries but could not find a good way of actually doing this
This is what I have so far and it is still not what I need and may not actually work.

```py
while output[child_string + str(child_count)].isNull.count < output.count():
    # Use child_X and find in DataObject
    # Then make a new column with child + new number of children mapped 
    # First get the found child column
    # current_child_col = output.select([child_string + str(child_count)])
    # current_child_col = mini_out.withCoObjectlumnRenamed(child_string + str(child_count), child_string + str(child_count + 1))
```

Comment: Desired output would make it easier to understand what you need done.

Comment: Good point @wwnde I have added that to the top. Thank you